# Is there an English word for a dedicated collector?

Tags: word-usage

Is there an English word for a person who "voraciously" collects objects of his or her interest?

Comment: What do you mean by "voraciously" in scare quotes? (Are they used as scare quotes?) Do you mean something like speculative collectors? Or maybe [compulsive hoarders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_hoarding)?

Comment: Are you looking for a noun?   Or an adjective that could be applied to the noun **collector**?

Comment: I am looking for a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the below word:

**completist**

The definition from Google is as follows:

completist

kəmˈpliːtist/

noun

noun: completist; 
plural noun: completists

> > an obsessive, typically indiscriminate, collector or fan of something.
> >
> > "this compilation of singles and B-sides has it usefulness for completists"

dictionary.com defines the same word as:

noun

> > 1.a person who attempts to complete a collection or set, especially a collector who wants to collect an example of every item in a particular field:
> >
> > This recording is a must for obsessive Sinatra completists.
> >
> > I'd only recommend this movie to Hepburn Completists.

This best suits the behaviour mentioned.

Comment: Is this word commonly used among native speakers?

Comment: It was identified in this 2007 work as a neologism that appeared in the late 1960s. https://books.google.com/books?id=lJCS0reqmFUC&pg=PA25&dq=%22completist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR1vvQ39zPAhVQET4KHQSvCNIQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22completist%22&f=false